# Connect Firebase with React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to connect React Native with Firebase. I'm using the following method to connect Firebase.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<YOUR-API-KEY>",
  authDomain: "<YOUR-AUTH-DOMAIN>",
  databaseURL: "<YOUR-DATABASE-URL>",
  storageBucket: "<YOUR-STORAGE-BUCKET>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


app.authWithPassword({
  "email": "abc@abc.com",
  "password": "abc1234"
}, (error, user_data) => {
  if (error) {
    alert('Login Failed. Please try again');
  } else {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(user_data));
  }
});
```

But it returns the following error:

> app.authWithPassword is not a function.

I'm using Firebase *3.4* and React Native *0.32*.

Comment: try `firebase.authWithPassword` instead of `app.authWithPassword`

Answer (score 3):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```